# Transferring out of GoDaddy: Is there a method for fast transfer with manual approval?

Tags: domain, godaddy

I have a domain registered at GoDaddy that I want to transfer to another registrar.

I initiated the transfer at the other registrar and then received an email from GoDaddy that says,

> We've received your request to transfer [domain_name] on [request_date]. Right now, we're preparing to move your domain — you don't need to do anything else. If you've changed your mind, you've got until [request_date + 5_days] to cancel the transfer.
>
> **We'll automatically approve your transfer within 5 days from your transfer request date.** Any products or services connected to [domain_name] will stay in your account after the transfer completes, but they may stop working as expected.

Do I have to wait the full 5 days or can I approve it sooner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to wait 5 days for GoDaddy to auto-approve the registrar transfer.

You can manually approve it from the list of pending domain transfers on [GoDaddy's Transfer Page](https://dcc.godaddy.com/control/transfers).

That same page also includes links to initiate a new domain transfer into GoDaddy or to move domains registered with GoDaddy to a different GoDaddy account.